# Is this operator a Fourier multiplier operator?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I want to study the Fourier transform of $$L_{\alpha}(t) = \frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{t^2} - i\frac{\alpha}{t}$$

Basically i am trying to get a grip on, given a $f$, what is $f(t)\ast L_{\alpha}(t)$ and am looking at $L_{\alpha}\ast$ as a Fourier multiplier operator.

Motivation : [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/210787/14414)

My main motivation was taking derivative of $f\ast\text{p.v.}\frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{t}$ and from comments I realize that its more appropriate to take a distributional derivative of this itself. So my question is on derivative of $f\ast\text{p.v.}\frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{t}$

Comment: Can this be made into a tempered distribution? I think the second term is well-behaved (as it'll yield only a multiple of the Hilbert Transform), but I don't know if we can make sense of the first one...

Comment: @JoãoRamos : Yes, please feel free to use distributions. Ultimately I am tryinng to solve this problem, and I hope distributions can take me there. http://mathoverflow.net/a/210787/14414

Comment: You need to be clearer. Are you trying to compute $\mathcal{F}(f\ast L_{\alpha})$? If so, then (distributionally) you get $\mathcal{F}f\cdot\mathcal{F}L_{\alpha}$. The Fourier transform of $L_{\alpha}$ is nothing more than $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(-(\alpha +\omega)\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha +\omega) +\alpha \operatorname{sgn}(\omega)\right).$$ So that expression above is the multiplier operator that $L_{\alpha}$ becomes under the Fourier transform.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : I dont want to compute Fourier transform of $f$, $f$ is a generic function in my analysis. So What you said is true, I want Fourier transform of $L_{\alpha}$ and then I multiply it with FT of $f$. I don't know much about distributions, so I don't get what is not clearer, it appears to me that you have answered my question, but I don't know how to deal with distributions, perhaps that where I am missing the point.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : It would be great if you can explain it in an answer, and how to make sense of a distribution.

Comment: I was just verifying your setup in my first line. The expression I gave is the Fourier transform of $L_{\alpha}$ as you desired.

Comment: @RajeshD First, you should note that the defining integral for the convolution does not in general converge - that makes us want to consider another way to 'force' convergence. This yields the concept of principal value - and it is in this sense that the convolution should be taken.

Comment: @JoãoRamos : I understand the integral won't converge, I want to understand how I can use this distribution conceptually, in my problem. It appears that the rules are different here with distributions than functions (as per my experience) but I dont know the rules.

Comment: @RajeshD Of course. I am just stating that you should check that $ t \mapsto \frac{ e^{i\alpha t}}{t^2} $ really defines a distribution.

Comment: @JoãoRamos Consider $f(t)*\frac{e^{i \alpha t}}{t}$, I want to take a derivative of this and then look at it as a  fourier multiplier acting on $f$,  but looks like such a thing is possible only through tempered distribution. Please look at this answer and suggest me something how to move forward.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Consider $f(t)*\frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{t}$, I want to take a derivative of this and then look at it as a fourier multiplier acting on f, but looks like such a thing is possible only through tempered distribution. Please look at this answer and suggest me something how to move forward.

Comment: @RajeshD I think that something you can do is to consider this 'function' as the distributional derivative of $ \text{p.v.}\;\frac{-e^{it\alpha}}{t} $. In this sense, you can find its Fourier Transform by Cameron's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from a comment above, I assume that this is what you should do in order to have your operator as a Fourier Multiplier one (or, more essentially, as a well-defined one!)

STEP 1: First, you should correct a bit the notion of $f * \frac{e^{it \alpha}}{t} $: this, in general, does not converge, so that, to make clear what this means to be, you should probably state that you want to differentiate the operator $ f * \{ \text{p.v. } \frac{e^{it \alpha}}{t} \}$. Taking a closer look:

$$ \text{p.v. } \frac{e^{it\alpha}}{t} * f (x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|y-x|\ge \epsilon} \frac{f(y)e^{i(x-y)\alpha}}{x-y} dy \\  = \pi e^{i\alpha x} \mathcal{H}(e^{-iy\alpha}f) $$

Where $\mathcal{H}$ Denotes the Hilbert Transform (click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform))

STEP 2: So, to differentiate this function, we should, somehow, differentiate the Hilbert Transform. One way to do this is to differentiate the tempered distribution $\text{p.v. } \frac{1}{t} $. We recall some basic concepts:

> Let $f \in \mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R}) $, and $u \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$. We define $u' \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ as the unique tempered distribution that satisfies
>
> $$ u'(f) =  u(f') \; \forall f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$$

From the alternative definition of the Hilbert Transform (i.e., $ (\mathcal{H}f)^{\wedge} = - i \;\text{sgn} \hat{f} $ ) we see that $ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \mathcal{H}f ( x) = \mathcal{H} \left( \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} f \right) (x) $, at least if $f \in \mathcal{S} ( \mathbb{R})$.

STEP 3: Looking back to our problem, we can, using the product rule to differentiate, get that

$$ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left( \text{p.v. } \frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{t} * f (x) \right) = \pi (i\alpha e^{i\alpha x} \mathcal{H}(e^{-i\alpha y} f) + e^{i\alpha x} \mathcal{H} ( e^{-iy\alpha}(-i\alpha f + f')) ) = \pi e^{ix \alpha} \mathcal{H} (e^{-iy\alpha}f') $$

Using some basic rules of the Fourier Transform, when we pass it on the last expression for $ f \in \mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R})$, we get something like

$$- \pi i \text{ sgn}(\theta - \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}) \hat{f'}(\theta) = - \pi i \cdot (2\pi i \theta) \text{ sgn}(\theta - \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}) \hat{f}(\theta) = 2 \pi^2 \theta \text{ sgn} (\theta - \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}) \hat{f}(\theta)   $$

And this gives your desired Fourier Multiplier.

**Remark 1**: Note that this is almost the same as Cameron's result - maybe the reason is that, here, I am defining

$$ \hat{f} (\xi) = \int f(t) e^{-2\pi i t \xi} \text{d} t $$

And the fact that, in his arguing, he was looking at your operator, instead of the definition that I gave here.

**Remark 2**: Your original operator is likely not the distributional derivative of the Operator we are dealing with - in fact, if you look carefully for some smooth function $ f $ such that $\text{supp} f \subseteq [-1,1]$, $f\equiv 1 $ in a neighborhood of 1, then the second summand converges on the principal value sense, but the first one does not - and that makes impossible the study of the operator you wrote there. So, if one really wants to differentiate the way you did, the best way to do it is with the help of distributions and the fine properties of the Hilbert Transform.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. Will get back soon as I am on vacation.

Comment: I don't get what two variables $x$,$y$ doing in this single expression $$\pi e^{i\alpha x} \mathcal{H}(e^{-iy\alpha}f) $$, and $t$ not appearing, may be I assume $x$ was taken instead of $t$ but what is $y$ doing in it. This I think I probably not getting the context here, as I am not having working knowledge on distributions. It would help if you could throw some light on it.

Comment: Well, there is a bit of confusion here, really. As you pointed out, $x$ is taking the place of $t$. The $y$ factor is not really important; that is, I mean that $\mathcal{H}(e^{-i \alpha y} f)$ is just applying the operator $\mathcal{H}$ on the function $ e^{-i \alpha y} f(y)$, and evaluate it at the point $x$. That said, the expression you are confused with is just an expression depending on x - $y$ was just a matter of notation.

Comment: Ah, then I feel $x$ should replace $y$ in the expression sitting inside the Hilbert operator, that would avoid confusion and there really isnt any need for $y$ when we can do with $x$. I mean we cannot write for example $f(x) \ast g(y) \ast h(t)$ right we just have to write $f(t)\ast y(t) \ast h(t)$ . Correct me if I got it wrong. I agree you needed $y$ inside the integral to explain principal value, but later it can be avoided.

Comment: @RajeshD Yeah, totally... We may change it for $x$. Sorry for the misunderstood. I'm in a hurry now, so I'll fix it later. Thanks for these remarks!

Comment: ok, no problem. I should really thank you for the nice answer.

Comment: You know my motivational problem, so why not substitute this expression there and take it  forward to see what can be done in proving it, I offer you a joint publication!

Comment: If you don't find it interesting, then no problem.

Comment: @RajeshD Well, why not? I'll take a look at it later, let's try to figure something out together :)

Comment: great! looking forward

Comment: In my case, $f$ is a generic function, it may contain jump discontinuties. Basically it is a function of bounded variation. So how can I handle this definition in my problem?